# Dart: sort list of maps by double

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of maps in dart that I would like to sort.

The list I use:

```
List<myModel> myList;
```

(with maps inside):

(I created a model called 'myModel', so if I want to get the views: so I can use: myList[index].views to get the views of a map).

I tried this code:

```
setState(() {
        filteredList = SplayTreeMap.from(
            myList,
            (a, b) => int.parse(myList[a].views)
                .compareTo(int.parse(myList[b].views)));
      });
```

(I want to sort the views, hight to low).

But I get this error:

```
error: A value of type 'SplayTreeMap' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<myModel>'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I 'query' my list this way.

```
    filteredList = myList
        .where((snapshot) => snapshot.views > 0)
        .toList();
```

This works...

Is there a possibility to sort that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a `List` to `SplayTreeMap.from(...)`.

See the [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/SplayTreeMap.from.html):

```dart
SplayTreeMap.from(Map other, [int compare(K key1 K key2), bool isValidKey(dynamic potentialKey)])
```

You need to use a `Map` or otherwise use `SplayTreeMap.fromIterable(...)` ([documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/SplayTreeMap.fromIterable.html)):

```dart
SplayTreeMap.fromIterable(Iterable iterable, {K key(dynamic element), V value(dynamic element), int compare(K key1 K key2), bool isValidKey(dynamic potentialKey)})
```

You could implement in the following way:

```dart
final filteredList = 
    SplayTreeMap.fromIterable(
      myList,
      key: (m) => m,
      value: (m) => m.views,
      compare: (a, b) => 
        int.parse(a.views).compareTo(int.parse(b.views))
    );
```

The above is an example, adjust it to your needs.

**EDIT 2:**
Given your edit, you could do something like:

```dart
final temp = List.from(myList);
temp.sort((a, b) => int.parse(a.views).compareTo(int.parse(b.views)));

filteredList = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I implement it in my case?

Comment: @KarelDebedts I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks! I still get the error: A value of type 'SplayTreeMap' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<myModel>'.

Comment: I updated my question, because 'querying' works, is there a way to sort like that?

Comment: @KarelDebedts what's the type of `filteredList`? Is it `List<myModel>`?

Comment: Yes, it's a List<myModel>

Comment: @KarelDebedts you cannot assign a `SplayTreeMap` to a `List`. The `filteredList` is a `List<myModel>` and you are trying to assign `SplayTreeMap` to it, those two types are incompatible with each other.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand, is there a possibility to sort the list (another way?).

Comment: @KarelDebedts you are welcome =). Glad I could help!